# lmer - linear mixed model- formula optimisation assistance for experimental analysis

Tags: r, linear-regression, lme4

I have conducted an experiment using some insects. The insects are placed in different concentrations of chemical and their movement measured over 24h by a machine.

Here was the lmer() formula divised:

`M1_Xa24D=lmer(value~concentration+machine+history+population+1|population/genotype/replicate)+(1|batch)+(1|machine/Well),data=Xa24D,REML=FALSE,  control = lmerControl(optimizer ="Nelder_Mead"))`

Is this formaula the missing something, given the definitions below?

**concentration**: concentration of chemical placed in.

**History**: whether they had been pre-exposed to the chemical prior to the experiment.

**Population**: which population an insect belongs to.

**Genotype**: a name is assigned to insects which are clones of each other

**machine** - which machine insects were placed in  (placed in one of two available measuring machines)

**Well**: insects were placed in a well (one well per insect), 12 wells per tray. 1 tray was placed into each machine.

**Batches**: same experiment was run on different days. different repeats of the experiment were called batches.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: You will have to tell me - which hypothesis do you want to test? In this setup, you are modelling _a lot_ of factors. To translate your formula, you are asking to find the effect of `concentration`, `machine`, `history`, and `population` on `value`, with random effects on `population/genotype/replicate` altogether, adjusting for `batch` and `machine/Well`.

Comment: it is expected that the concentration and history will affect the "value" (distance moved) of the insects. Given this, I expect the degree to which they are effected to vary according to population.